# Regular expression to remove leading/trailing zeros from a string

Tags: java, regex

Is this the proper REGEX to remove trailing decimal and zeroes from a string? I can't get it to work. What am I missing?

> 78.80 -> 78.8

```
str.replaceAll("^.0*$", "");
```

i need only 2 decimal points as well like 78.008 should be 78.01

and if it is 78.10 the 78.1 only.

Comment: @tbsalling even with the same number ;)

Comment: no I have some addition in that...

Comment: Remember to show *a representative sample of input*. Also, your "new addition" is nothing like the original. **Changing "78.008" to "78.01" not the same a "remove .. trailing zeros"**. Let's please close this question. Open up another question that asks the "right thing", which might be: "How can I print a float with at most 2 decimals of precision?" (but *make sure to search first*).

Comment: Is there any reason why you're not treating it as a float or double? Are you using regex for converting it from `78.008` to `78.01`? hmm..

Comment: ok but the this is editable ... ok thanks

Comment: Don't forget about http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/10998/what-does-the-jamie-zawinskis-quotation-about-regular-expressions-mean. Are you trying to print a number with specific precision and just happen to choose RE for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the correct regular expression is something more complex, and it needs positive look-behind.

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\.0*$|(?<=\\.[0-9]{0,2147483646})0*$", "");
```

you have to escape the `.`, because otherwise it means "any character", you have to anchor the regex only to the end of the string, and you have to say that the `0` digits must be after a `.` plus some optional non-zero digits.

Addendum: there is a "special case" that should be handled: `1.00`. We handle it by using the `|`. The first sub-expression means "a dot plus only zeroes" and matches even the dot (that in this way is deleted)

And remember that in Java strings are immutable, so `replaceAll` will create a new string.

Note the use of `{0,2147483646}`: if you used a `*` you would get a `Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length`, because the `*` would be converted to `{0,2147483647}` and considering the "+1" length of the `\\.` it would overflow, so we put the maximum number of digits possible (2147483647, maximum value of a signed int) minus 1 for the dot.

Test example: http://ideone.com/0NDTSq

Comment: I had modified it to include a `.` (the OP decimal separator)

Comment: no change require in that. 8700 should be 8700

Comment: That's the regex I was going to post (a little different: `(?<=\d+\.[1-9]*)0*`, to make sure there are digits before the `.`), but @yiannis posted a better solution. The only downside of it is that it will convert `78.000` into `78.`.

Comment: @OscarMederos Changed adding the special case

Comment: @xanatos +1. now I think it is perfect (if you include `\d` before the `.`) `:)`

Comment: That regex in java throws an exception "Look-behind group does not have an obvious maximum length" can it be updated to handle this error ?

Comment: @george_h Modified and added an example on ideone

Comment: this throws: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Decimal number is too large near index 32: \.0*$|(?<=\.[0-9]{0,2147483646})0*$
        ^

Answer (score 2):

Since you want rounding of the numbers, you should not use regular expressions. You should use `DecimalFormat`:

```
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
Double d = Double.parseDouble("123.078");
String s = twoDForm.format(d);
System.out.println(s);
```

will output:

```
123.08
```

Comment: That's the way to go.

Comment: yes i use same but the problem is 8.80 required output is 8.8 then..

Comment: DecimalFormat("#.#"); will remove all trailing zeros...

Answer (score 1):

With the anchors `^` and `$` you are trying to match the whole string and replace it. And this will not match since there is more in the string.

Try this

```
 str.replace("0*$", "");
```

With `0*$` you will match only 0 or more "0" at the end of the string.

**Note:** This will also change "1000" to "1"!

Comment: +1 for specifying that it will also change `1000` to `1`.